# How can I limit GridView to the size of the screen and adapt the elements inside to different devices?

Tags: flutter, dart, gridview, grid

I have a GridView in which I will transfer from 3-12 elements, I would like all these elements to fit on the screen without scrolling.

I tested on Pixel 2 devices and a device with a size of 6.7. Using `childAspectRatio` I selected the ratio that suits me for these two devices `childAspectRatio: (1 / 0.8),`. And also disabled the scroll for centering when the elements do not occupy the entire screen.

```
shrinkWrap: true,
physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
```

But this method does not seem very beautiful to me, and with 12 elements in Pixel 2, they no longer fit. Could you tell me how to make the transmitted elements shrink inside the GridView depending on the need and occupy only the screen space ?

```
      Expanded(
            child: Container(
            // height: size   * 2,
            // padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
            color: Colors.red,
            child: Center(
              child: GridView(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
    crossAxisCount: 3,
    mainAxisSpacing: 5,
    crossAxisSpacing: 5,   
    childAspectRatio: (1 / 0.8),
    
  ),
  
  children: [
    Padding(
padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
child: Container( color: Colors.grey,
child: 

  Image.network('https://picsum.photos/250?image=1'), padding: EdgeInsets.all(3),
    ),
    ),
   Padding(
padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
child: Container( color: Colors.grey,
child: 

  Image.network('https://picsum.photos/250?image=1'), padding: EdgeInsets.all(3),
    ),
    ),
    Padding(
padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
child: Container( color: Colors.grey,
child: 

  Image.network('https://picsum.photos/250?image=1'), padding: EdgeInsets.all(3),
    ),
    ),
         
  ],
        
),
            ),        
            ),
          flex:10         
          ),
```

GridView is located in the red area

[image: Its Pixel 2 with 12 elements and scroll problem]
[image: Its Pixel 2 with 6 elements]
[image: Its 6.7 with 6 elements]
[image: Its 6.7 with 12 elements]

Comment: I think you just need image fit: `Boxfit.cover`

Comment: I don't think it will help me. I plan to load the image deleted and as you can see they are in a container, that is, the gridview element is the container in which the image is located.

Answer (score 0):

Trying using: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view
This package gives you multiple option and also helps you to make GridView Responsive